# Equivalent of Pipe | in PowerShell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, shell, scripting

Greeting,

So, the issue is that when I run the command

`($env:NAME="STOCK_BROKER") && ($env:TOPIC_ID="stock_prices") ; node publisher.mjs`

I have to input a message on my own.

I'm trying to run a loop and the result of each iteration pass into my node process (imitating a user's input), one process on top of the other.

`for ($i = 1 ; $i -le 1000 ; $i++) { sleep 1; echo "New Price"; } | ($env:NAME="BROKER") && ($env:TOPIC_ID="prices") ; node publisher.mjs`

I get an error since PowerShell doesn't know what pipe symbol means...

Comment: Do you want to send all 1000 messages to the same `node` process at once, or pipe them to `node` one by one?

Comment: Yes, I want to pipe them to node one after another. Node process should run all the time, but on top of it the loop has to execute each second a message "New price" imitating a user's input.

Comment: You'll want something like `1..1000 |ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep 1; "New Price" } | node publisher.mjs` then (you can set the `$env:*` variables once, before this statement, no need to do it immediately before `node`)

Comment: For goodness sake, mate, if you were close to me right now I would definitely hug you! Thanks! I spent an hour at least trying to figure out how to run it. 